# iptables blocking all outbound connections

Tags: iptables

I have the following rules set up:

```
  iptables -F
  iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
  iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
  iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
  iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12344 -j ACCEPT
  iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
  iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

For some reason all outbound traffic is blocked, even though `iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT` is set.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Fisrtly, can we see your whole ruleset (paste the output of `iptables -L -n -v` into the question).   Secondly, could you show us an example of "*all outbound traffic [being] blocked*"?  Your `INPUT` rules don't allow any DNS responses, for example, so I suspect that's more likely the issue than the blocking of outbound traffic.

Comment: @MadHatter Thanks, you were right, it was a combination of not having a rule to allow DNS connections and also David's answer. When I added the rules for DNS I saw it was resolving hosts but server was still not getting responses. After I've added the rule that David metnioned it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is most likely issues relating to the returning traffic being rejected.
Try adding a new line 2 reading

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

To allow connections related to outbound connections you made to go through.

Comment: I've just added that rule, still not getting through

Comment: I wouldn't add the `RELATED`, unless I was sure I needed it.  Many do, but it's always struck me as cargo-cult programming.  It leaves your state engine entirely at the mercy of your current set of loaded kernel modules.

Comment: The next thing to do might be to try a tcpdump to see what traffic is hitting your router, then trying to make a connection and see whats going on.   Also, can you confirm that the Linux is a host and not a router.  (If its a router you need to look at the FORWARD chain).  Can you do an iptables -vnL and provide more details of a specific thing which is failing ?)

Comment: @madHatter - I like being able to use FTP and other (what I consider broken protocols) without too much fiddling around, but yes, for simple HTTP type connections you can leave out related.

Comment: Thanks, adding this rule and also allowing DNS connections did the trick